# How to delay a cmd+Q in the same way as the Caps Lock is delayed?

Tags: macos, keyboard

On my Mid-2009 MacBook Pro the Caps Lock button has a convenient delay such that when I hit it accidentally it doesn't turn on immediately.
Can I incorporate such a delay for another key combination?
I would like to delay the <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> shortcut such that when I accidentally hit it the application is not quit and I have time to recover.